# python sockets for beginner

Tags: python, sockets

I know python and am trying to get into more complicated stuff.  I found this code and it supposedly worked.  I am getting the error on line 14 of the client, the return of mrecv
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10; ''

I have the two files seperated and call the server, then the client. When I run them the server just say
    Closing
and the client says
    recieved-> bye!!!
and nothing happens, but when i type hello into the client I get the error I showed above. I am probably/possibly doing something wrong, this is my first time doing anything with sockets or servers or whatever.  If you know what I am doing wrong please help, also if you have any other good websites or tutorials for me I would appreciate it.  Here is all the code (not mine)

python socket chat example,
author: Ankur Shrivastava,
licence: GPL v3

## server

```
import socket
import threading
import time

SIZE = 4

soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
soc.bind(('127.0.0.1',5432))
soc.listen(5)

class CThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,c):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.conn = c
        self.stopIt=False

    def mrecv(self):
        data = self.conn.recv(SIZE)
        self.conn.send('OK')
        msg = self.conn.recv(int(data))
        return msg

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopIt:
            msg = self.mrecv()
            print 'recieved->  ',msg

def setConn(con1,con2):
    dict={}
    state = con1.recv(9)
    con2.recv(9)
    if state =='WILL RECV':
        dict['send'] = con1 # server will send data to reciever
        dict['recv'] = con2
    else:
        dict['recv'] = con1 # server will recieve data from sender
        dict['send'] = con2
    return dict

def msend(conn,msg):
    if len(msg)<=999 and len(msg)>0:
        conn.send(str(len(msg)))
        if conn.recv(2) == 'OK':
            conn.send(msg)
    else:
        conn.send(str(999))
        if conn.recv(2) == 'OK':
            conn.send(msg[:999])
            msend(conn,msg[1000:]) # calling recursive


(c1,a1) = soc.accept()
(c2,a2) = soc.accept()
dict = setConn(c1,c2)
thr = CThread(dict['recv'])
thr.start()
try:
    while 1:
        msend(dict['send'],raw_input())
except:
    print 'closing'
thr.stopIt=True
msend(dict['send'],'bye!!!')# for stoping the thread
thr.conn.close()
soc.close()
```

## client

```
import socket
import threading
SIZE =4
class client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,c):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.conn = c
        self.stopIt = False

    def mrecv(self):
        data = self.conn.recv(SIZE)
        self.conn.send('OK')
        return self.conn.recv(int(data))

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopIt:
            msg = self.mrecv()
            print 'recieved-> ',msg

soc1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
soc1.connect(('127.0.0.1',5432))
soc1.send('WILL SEND') # telling server we will send data from here

soc2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
soc2.connect(('127.0.0.1',5432))
soc2.send('WILL RECV') # telling server we will recieve data from here

def msend(conn,msg):
    if len(msg)<=999 and len(msg)>0:
        conn.send(str(len(msg)))
        if conn.recv(2) == 'OK':
            conn.send(msg)
    else:
        conn.send(str(999))
        if conn.recv(2) == 'OK':
            conn.send(msg[:999])
            msend(conn,msg[1000:]) # calling recursive
thr = client(soc2)
thr.start()
try:
    while 1:
        msend(soc1,raw_input())
except:
    print 'closing'
thr.stopIt=True
msend(soc1,'bye!!') # for stoping the thread
thr.conn.close()
soc1.close()
soc2.close()
```

I tried typing in a number and it gives me the same error.  When i take out int from the line and run the client it says that it has to be a number... any other ideas?

Comment: The codes appear to be working for me.

Comment: really? how are you running/calling it?

Comment: your write. I tried to type it all so now i have little mistakes. Should have thought of that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The receiver expects 4 bytes of string data to signify the length of the remaining data to be received. In this case, your first four bytes don't contain a valid text-integer (like "1234"), so the call to `int()` is failing.